# Serializing a map of custom types to JSON using Scala and Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

I created a Map of custom types by using information found here http://www.blaenkdenum.com/notes/play/:

```
def getAllProductsWithStockItems: Map[Product, List[StockItem]] = {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        val sql = SQL("select p.*, s.*" +
        "from products p" +
        "inner join stock_items s on (p.id = s.product_id)")

        val results: List[(Product, StockItem)] = sql.as(productStockItemParser *)

    results.groupBy { _._1 }.mapValues { _.map { _._2 } }
    }
}
```

I need to serialize/deserialize `Map[Product, List[StockItem]]` into JSON, but I don't really know how to do it. I already have working serializers for both custom types (Product and StockItem) which I coded using Play's native JSON library, but I can use another one if it's better. Can someone give me some pointers?

---

**Update**: The List/StockItem example is not a good one, but it's just an abstraction. In the end, I have a structure which represents 1 to n relationships.
So, considering each Product has a list of StockItem, I expect the JSON to look like something similar to this:

```
{
"products": [
            {
                "id": 1
                "productName": "coffee",
                "stockitems": [   
                               {
                                   "id":1,
                                   "brandName": "Crazycoffee",
                                   "price": 5
                                   "quantity": 3000
                               },
                               {
                                   "id":2,
                                   "brandName": "Badcoffee",
                                   "price": 1
                                   "quantity": 2000
                               }
                               ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1
                "productName": "ice cream",
                "stockitems": [   
                               {
                                   "id":1,
                                   "brandName": "Sleazyice",
                                   "price": 2
                                   "quantity": 300
                               }
                               ]
            }
            ]
}
```

Comment: How would you expect the generated json to look?

Comment: This looks like a List[Product]

Comment: You mentioned that you have working serializers. Can we see what they look like?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it is writing from part of my working java code. Using Jackson library (included in play 2) :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public static String toJson(Map<Product, List<StockItem>> lst)
{
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter();
    try{
        JsonGenerator gen = factory.createGenerator(writer);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName("infos");
        gen.writeRaw(":" + listToJson(lst));
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.close();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        Logger.error("AjaxRequest.generateResponse: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(writer.toCharArray());
}

/**
 * Convert a list into a json string.
 */
public static String listToJson(List<?> lst) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter();
    JsonGenerator gen = factory.createGenerator(writer);
    gen.writeRaw(mapper.writeValueAsString(lst));
    gen.close();
    return new String(writer.toCharArray());
}
```

Jackson library work well, but is so far from being easy to understand. Anyway, with few modifications, this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated , then you could save some time while not having to write all the Writers and Readers by hand. You could create a "wrapper" entity based on your top level JSON element "products" such as ProductsList (for example). Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
case class ProductList (
  list: Vector[Product]
)

object ProductList {

  /**
    * Mapping to and from JSON.
    */
  implicit val documentFormatter: Format[ProductList] = (
    (__ \ "products").format[Vector[Product]]
  ) (ProductList.apply, unlift(ProductList.unapply))

}
```